# Loop must iterate over collection: Webinar_Attendees__c

Tags: apex, soql, collection

I'm trying to print sub query fields but I got the error like "Loop must iterate over collection: Webinar_Attendees__c".

```
          list<Webinar_Attendees__c> re = [SELECT Id,Login__c,Name,Opportunity__c,WebinarContact__c,Voucher_Number__c,Email_Sent__c, LastModifiedDate,(select Id,Name,Voucher_Assign_Date__c    from Voucher_Repository__r  )
                                     FROM Webinar_Attendees__c WHERE Voucher_Number__c != Null AND CreatedDate <= TODAY 
                                     ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC NULLS FIRST LIMIT : limitsize OFFSET : count];   

     for(Webinar_Attendees__c web : re){

         for(Voucher_Repository__c rep : web){

            Date dateField = rep.Voucher_Assign_Date__c;

         }
     }
```

Thanks,
RAGHU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`web` is a variable of type `Webinar_Attendees__c`. It is not a collection, and cannot be used in an iteration. To access subquery results, you must use the relationship name given in the child query as a property on the parent. This value will be typed as a `List<sObject>`, where the sObject is the type of the child object.

```
     for(Voucher_Repository__c rep : web.Voucher_Repository__r){
```